# How do you doc-type an enum string in PHP?

Tags: php, enums, php-8.1

for doctyping a class-string you can doctype using: `class-string<ParentClassType>`.

But i cannot find any documentation surrounding enums.

I can find you can document something to be a value of an Enum with `value-fo<Enum>`
https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types.

But is there a doctype available for enums?
(i would expect something like? `enum-class`)

So the editor would know it can call `::tryFrom`, `::from` and `::cases()`

Comment: I'm confused, what are you looking for? From the title you want to doc-type a string, but in the end "know it can call", what does "it" represent? A string cannot call these methods.

Comment: @shingo in PHP a string can be a reference to a class and thus call it's static methods "ClassName"::method() is totally valid in PHP

Comment: Honestly I didn't realize strings can be used like this in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately all the enumerations implement the [UnitEnum](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.unitenum.php) interface, and all the backed enumerations implement the [BackedEnum](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.backedenum.php) interface, so you can use `class-string<UnitEnum>` to hint enumeration strings, and use `class-string<BackedEnum>` to hint backed enumeration strings.